# Error calling async method synchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, geolocation, async-await

I'm writing code in a desktop application that will be used in police cars to use the new Windows Geolocation API.  I've written an event listener for the `Geolocator.PositionChanged` event, but it's not getting called.  In my reading of the documentation, it seems that the `Gelocator` only raises this event when the position changes.

I figure the first thing my program should do after it finished setting up the event listener is to call the `Geolocator.GetPositionAsync` method to get the current position and then let the position get updated as they happen.

I need to call the `Geolocator.GetPositionAsync` method synchronously. To that end, I wrote the following method:

```
private async Task<Geoposition> GetCurrentPosition() {
    await Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
}
```

However, I get the following compiler error on the line with `await` in it:

> 'await' requires that the type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation' have a suitable GetAwaiter method. Are you missing a using directive for 'System'?

Here are the using statements at the top of the file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
```

How do I fix this compiler error?

**Edit**

After I added a reference to `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll` the project, the error went away.  However, now I'm getting a new error:

> 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geoposition>' does not contain a definition for 'IsCompleted'

How do I fix this one?

**Edit**

Here's the code that calls the method:

```
protected override void Initialize() {
    // Make sure we "forget" any previous Gelocator device
    if ( Geolocator != null ) {
        Geolocator.PositionChanged -= PositionChanged;
        Geolocator.StatusChanged   -= StatusChanged;
        Geolocator                  = null;
    }

    CurrentPosition = new GpsInformation() { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now };
    Geolocator = new Geolocator();
    Geolocator.DesiredAccuracy   = PositionAccuracy.High;    // Sends position updates with the highest accuracy possible.
    Geolocator.MovementThreshold = 0;                        // Sends position updates no matter how far the vehicle has moved since the last update.
    Geolocator.ReportInterval    = 0;                        // Sends position updates as they become availble.
    Geolocator.PositionChanged  += PositionChanged;          // Sends position updates to this method.
    Geolocator.StatusChanged    += StatusChanged;            // Sends status changed updates to this method.
    switch ( Geolocator.LocationStatus ) {
        case PositionStatus.Disabled:
        case PositionStatus.NotAvailable: 
            // The Geolocator device is disabled.  We won't get any updates.  Throw an exception.
            throw new Exception( "LPRCore does not have permission to use Windows Geolocation services or Geolocation services are not working." );
    }

    Task<Geoposition> getPositionTask = GetCurrentPosition();
    positionRecord = getPositionTask.Result;
}
```

Comment: You're sure you've got `using System;` in the same file that you've got the await expression? Also note that I suspect you want `return await Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();`

Comment: Yes, I do have the `using System;` in the saem file as the await expression.  I added the `return ` to the line & I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you Scott for your help.  I was able to figure out which DLLs to add references to from your suggestions & then hit-or-miss trying things.

To fix the problem, I needed to add references to:

- `System.Threading.dll` and
- `System.Threading.Tasks.dll`

Once I did this, the error went away.

I wish MS would add information about which DLLs need to be referenced to use the Windows 8 APIs from VS2012 to their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate question, but you should add a reference to System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll as well if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have that reference after all.  That got rid of that error, but now I'm getting another: 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geoposition>' does not contain a definition for 'IsCompleted'

Comment: Are you trying to subscribe to an IsCompleted event?  I feel like you have some code that we're not seeing here.

Comment: I'll add the call to that method to the OP.

Comment: All of the code that has to do with this call is now in the original question.

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but try referencing System.RunTime; as well.

Comment: Ok, two other things to try and then I'm all out of options.  Try adding a reference to System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll and try setting the target platform to x64 if you're on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: I should have added the references to the post. Yes, I already have a reference to `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll`.  And yes, I set the target platform to x64.  Didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you ran into this problem while trying to resolve the wrong issue.

While investigation to write my [Exposing the Geolocator as a Reactive Service](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Exposing_the_Geolocator_as_a_Reactive_Service) on the [Nokia Developer Wiki](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/) I came across the same problem (no change events) and tried the same solution (calling `Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync`).

It turns out that you need to set some properties (`Geolocator.MovementThreshold`, `Geolocator.DesiredAccuracy`, `Geolocator.ReportInterval`) with some values.

If you are not familiar with the [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh242985.aspx), you should try it. You can get my implementation from [my CodeProject Workspace](https://workspaces.codeproject.com/paulomorgado/reactive-geolocator/code).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm setting those properties to values I want to use and I wasn't getting any position updates.  Then again, it's using Wi-Fi to determine my machine's coordinates, so the position isn't likely to change.  Do you have any recommendations for values?