# How can i import windows.media.capture in my WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, windows-7-x64

I am really confused about windows media capture namespace, I would like to import the namespace to develop camera function in windows 8.1.

FYI, I developed using visual studio 2013 and windows 7 64 bit, i already tried to install windows 8 Software Development Kits also, but i still can't find the namespace.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can only use that namespace in Store and Phone projects, not in desktop projects like WPF.  Google "wpf camera capture", lots of hits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I've done developing app for windows 8.1 Table in Windows 7 x64 and want to share some experience that i had in here.

Steps :

1. Edit .csproject in wpf app (Add `<TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>` Inside `<PropertyGroup>` )
2. Add "Windows" library Reference
   [image: Add Windows Reference]
3. Load some .Net Framework 4 Library (System.Runtime.dll, System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll,System.Threading and System.Threading.Task ) the location usually in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
4. Load System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5)

But we cannot debug the application because have different runtime with windows 7, we only can build and deploy to the Windows 8.1 Tablet.

I've done implementing camera function, GPS and database operation using MSSQLServer Compact DB Express 2014.

Reference :

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/10/29/how-to-use-specific-winrt-api-from-desktop-apps-capturing-a-photo-using-your-webcam-into-a-wpf-app.aspx
- [Error calling async method synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255490/error-calling-async-method-synchronously)

Answer (score 0):

**Windows.media.capture** minimum supported client is windows 8 and minimum supported phone is windows phone 8.1.

Check this Article from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.aspx)

Comment: I already install windows 8 in virtual machine and install visual studio 2013 again, buat still cannot find the namespace, any idea?

Comment: Whether you installed visualstudio 2013 in Windows 8?